# C++ Preprocessor Decisions

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

Sorry I know this is basic, but perhaps it doesn't exist or I'm not googling the right words.
Is there and an `if not` (is that `ifndef`?) an `AND` and an `OR` so I could do something like:

```
if not DEBUG and MACOS
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think something like `#if !defined(DEBUG) && defined(MACOS)` should do it.

Answer (score 3):

`#ifndef and #if` do different things so it depends on what you want.  `#ifndef` is true when there is no defined preprocessor symbol that matches the name following.  `#if` is true when the following preprocessor expression evaluates to non-zero.

You can use the standard && and || operators.

Answer (score 3):

```
#if !defined(DEBUG) && defined(MACOS)
#error "Ouch!"
#endif
```

tests, if those macros/values are defined (even set to 0 means defined). Leave out the "defined()" and test again a value, depending on your macros, like

```
#if DEBUG==0 && MACOS==1
#error "Spam!"
#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#if !DEBUG && MACROS
```

or

```
#if !DEBUG & !MACROS
```

depending on what you are looking for.  defined() can also help

```
#if !defined(DEBUG) && defined(MACROS)
```

Answer (score 1):

`#if !(defined(DEBUG) && defined(MACOS))`

or

`#if !defined(DEBUG) && !defined(MACOS)`

depending on what you're trying to evaluate.

Answer (score 1):

`#if`, `#else` and `#endif` are general.
Use `#define` to declare and `#undef` to undeclare.
Use `#ifdef` to check if is declared and `#ifndef` to check, if is not declared.

Example:

```
#ifndef LABEL
#define LABEL some_value // declares LABEL as some_value
#else
#undef LABEL // undeclare previously declared LABEL...
#define LABEL new_value // to declare a new_value
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Boost preprocessing library. It can accomplish a large number of tasks using the preprocessor.